# How do I edit files in a docker image?

Tags: directory, structure, project, edit, docker

I am just setting up docker on my local machine for web-dev.

I have seen lots of tutorials for docker with rails etc...

I am curious how does docker work in terms of editing the projects source code.

I am trying to wrap my head around this `-v` tag.

In many of the tutorials I have seen users have stored their `Dockerfile` in the project base directory and the built from there, do you just edit the code in the directory and refresh the browser? And leave docker running.

Just trying to wrap my head around it all, sorry if basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually differentiate two use cases of Docker:

- in one case I want a Dockerfile that helps end users get started easily
- in another case I want a Dockerfile to help code contributors to have a testing environment up and running easily

For end users, you want your Dockerfile to

- install dependencies
- checkout the latests stable code (from github or elsewhere)
- setup some kind of default configuration

for contributors, you want your Dockerfile to

- install dependencies
- document how to run a Docker container setting up a volume to share the source code between their development environment and the docker container.

To sum up, for end users the Docker image should embed the application code while for contributors the docker image will just have the dependencies.